# Instantiate a pyephem EarthSatellite from positional coordinates without a TLE

Tags: pyephem

I have the position of a satellite at a given time, in altitude/latitude/longitude coordinates.

I'd like to calculate the azimuth/elevation from an observer on earth (given in lat/long) to this satellite at that position.

The ephem.EarthSatellite object only operates on TLEs and a desired timestamp. Is there anyway to instantiate a satellite from positional coordinates? Maybe with a different ephem.Body type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to create your own objects with Earth-fixed coordinates in PyEphem. You might want to take a look at its replacement that I am writing, though, called Skyfield — you should be able to create a `Topos` object with any lat / lon / elevation you want, and then observe it from any other location you define with a `Topos` and get an alt / az back.